# Hermitian matrix representation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I know that a Hermitian matrix is a square matrix with complex entries that is equal to its own conjugate transpose, i.e $H = H^{\dagger}.$ But why is $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$ Hermitian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner product in $\mathbb C^n$ is defined by $\displaystyle\langle a,b\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^n \bar a_k b_k$ where $\bar a_k$ is the complex conjugate of $a_k$.  This makes $\|a\|^2 =\langle a,a\rangle$ nonnegative.   The inner product of $a$ and $Hb$ is

$$
\langle a, Hb \rangle = a^\dagger Hb = a^\dagger H^\dagger b = (Ha)^\dagger b = \langle Ha,b\rangle.
$$

It is the case that $\langle a, Hb \rangle = \langle Ha,b\rangle$ if and only if $H=H^\dagger$.

Now define an inner product by

$$
\langle a,b\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \bar a(x)b(x)\,dx.
$$
Now ask whether
$$
\left\langle a,\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} b \right\rangle = \left\langle \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}a, b \right\rangle.
$$
If so, then $\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$ is Hermitian.

You can show that this holds by integrating by parts twice.

Comment: @Robben : The notation you say you usually see is something I've never seen, unless maybe a confused student wrote it.  $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} f$ is the first partial derivative.  $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} f$ is the second partial derivative, conventionally written as $\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} f$, just as $\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2} f$ is the second derivative with respect to one variable. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: If you're working in an a space of square-integrable functions (i.e. $\displaystyle\left\{f : \int_{\mathbb R^N} |f(\vec{x}|^2\,d\vec{x}<\infty\right\}$) then if you have an orthonormal basis of that space, there could be a infinite matrix, indexed by $n,m\in\mathbb Z$, that represents this operator.

Comment: For example, for the space of square-integrable functions of one variable on the set $[0,2\pi]$, the set of functions $\{x\mapsto e^{inx} : n\in\mathbb Z\}$ is an orthonormal basis.  You have $(d/dx)^2 e^{inx}= -n^2 e^{inx}$.  So the $(n,n)$ entry in the matrix would be $-n^2$ and all of the off-diagonal entries would be $0$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I see now, thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$ is an operator on some space of functions on a certain interval I.  To check that it is Hermitian you need an equality of the form 
$$\int_I \frac{\partial^2 \phi(x)}{\partial x^2} \cdot\bar  \psi(x) = \int_I  \phi(x) \frac{\partial^2 \bar\psi(x) }{\partial x^2} $$

(or, perhaps, the conjugations goes on the left, depending on convention)

Comment: Yes, in a precise space of functions. The inner product is $\langle \phi, \psi \rangle = \int_I \phi(x) \bar \psi(x) dx$.